# How to remove and reload cookie on any page click?

Tags: jquery, cookies

I have set up a cookie working called "popupVisit". Cookies are now working on all pages. However I need this to be removed and renewed when new pages are clicked. It will then remember those pages have been clicked and the cookie will remain.

Currently I have the below code going but doesn't work. The cookie remains on any links clicked, which makes sense with the code but not what I need. Any other way to get this to work, targeting any links?

```
$("a").click( function(e){
    $.removeCookie('popupVisit', { path: '/' });
    location.reload();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added this condition but not exactly smooth. It'll work.

```
if ( $.cookie('popupVisit') > 1 ) {
$("a").click( function(e){
    $.removeCookie('popupVisit', { path: '/' });
    location.reload();
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
$(document).on('click','a',function(e){
    if ( typeof $.cookie('popupVisit') !== 'undefined' ) {
       $.removeCookie('popupVisit', { path: '/' });
       location.reload();
    }   
});
```

$(document).on(... is better than  $(selector).click(...